# Mark moderator inbox item as read when I've read it

Tags: feature-request, notifications, moderator-tools, top-bar

As a moderator on a beta site, I receive a notification for every meta question. This notification was formerly delivered in my inbox (still is on Ask Ubuntu, blessed be its top bar while it lasts) and is now delivered in a new per-site moderator inbox.

Earlier a [question](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/790/electorate-badge-did-i-qualify-for-the-badge) was posted on CS Meta. I read it and even retagged and answered it. I also acknowledged the notification in the old-style inbox on AU. Yet the question still appeared in the moderator inbox on CS/Meta.CS.

The moderator inbox entry should be marked as read as soon as I've visited the meta question. When all moderator inbox entry are read, the inbox indicator in the top bar should not light up.